# Pandas tells me non-ambiguous time is ambiguous

Tags: pandas, timezone, dst

I have the following test code:

```
import pandas as pd

dt = pd.to_datetime('2021-11-07 01:00:00-0400').tz_convert('America/New_York')
pd.DataFrame({'datetime': dt,
              'value': [3, 4, 5]})
```

When using `pandas` version 1.1.5, this runs successfully.  But under `pandas` version 1.2.5 or 1.3.4, it fails with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    'value': [3, 4, 5]})
  File "venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 614, in __init__
    mgr = dict_to_mgr(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy, typ=manager)
  File "venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 465, in dict_to_mgr
    arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype, typ=typ, consolidate=copy
  File "venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 124, in arrays_to_mgr
    arrays = _homogenize(arrays, index, dtype)
  File "venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 590, in _homogenize
    val, index, dtype=dtype, copy=False, raise_cast_failure=False
  File "venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/construction.py", line 514, in sanitize_array
    data = construct_1d_arraylike_from_scalar(data, len(index), dtype)
  File "venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py", line 1907, in construct_1d_arraylike_from_scalar
    subarr = cls._from_sequence([value] * length, dtype=dtype)
  File "venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimes.py", line 336, in _from_sequence
    return cls._from_sequence_not_strict(scalars, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
  File "venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimes.py", line 362, in _from_sequence_not_strict
    ambiguous=ambiguous,
  File "venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimes.py", line 2098, in sequence_to_dt64ns
    data.view("i8"), tz, ambiguous=ambiguous
  File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/tzconversion.pyx", line 284, in pandas._libs.tslibs.tzconversion.tz_localize_to_utc
pytz.exceptions.AmbiguousTimeError: Cannot infer dst time from 2021-11-07 01:00:00, try using the 'ambiguous' argument
```

I am aware that Daylight Saving Time is happening on November 7.  But this data looks explicit to me, and fully localized; why is `pandas` forgetting its timezone information, and why is it refusing to put it in a `DataFrame`?  Is there some kind of workaround here?

**Update:**

I remembered that I'd actually filed a bug about this a few months ago, but it was only of somewhat academic interest to us until this week when we're starting to see actual DST-transition dates in production:  https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/42505

Comment: The issue occurs when trying to call `tz_localize_to_utc` during the `_homogenize` and `santize_array` phases of implicitly building the block manager for the column. [Here is the source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/arrays/datetimes.py#L2138-L2140)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's ambiguous because there are 2 dates with this special time: with DST and without DST:

```
# Timestamp('2021-11-07 01:00:00-0500', tz='America/New_York')
>>> pd.to_datetime('2021-11-07 01:00:00') \
      .tz_localize('America/New_York', ambiguous=False).dst()
datetime.timedelta(0)


# Timestamp('2021-11-07 01:00:00-0400', tz='America/New_York')
>>> pd.to_datetime('2021-11-07 01:00:00') \
      .tz_localize('America/New_York', ambiguous=True).dst()
datetime.timedelta(3600)
```

**Workaround**

```
dt = pd.to_datetime('2021-11-07 01:00:00-0400')

df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': dt,
                   'value': [3, 4, 5]})

df['datetime'] = df['datetime'].dt.tz_convert('America/New_York')
```

Comment: So interestingly the reasoning for this is not correct. `pd.DataFrame({'a': 1, 'b': [2, 3, 4]})` is a completely valid way to build a DataFrame. However, this does seem to fix the error in this case. Building the list explicitly avoids whatever process is done in trying to scale the constant up... I'm looking now for where the issue is happening

Comment: @HenryEcker. You're right. I updated my answer about the `ambiguous` error.

Comment: Yeah, as Henry says, `pd.DataFrame({'datetime': dt, 'value':[3,4,5]})` is supposed to be a valid call.

Comment: @KenWilliams. I updated my answer. Maybe you should also open an issue on githhub?

Comment: Thanks @Corralien - I did actually open a github issue (see update to question).  In fact, I opened it several months ago but then forgot the problem still existed.  This question/answer was still helpful to figure out a workaround, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I accepted @Corralien's answer, and I also wanted to show what workaround I finally decided to go with:

```py
# Work around Pandas DST bug, see https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/42505 and
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69846645/pandas-tells-me-non-ambiguous-time-is-ambiguous
max_len = max(len(x) if self.is_array(x) else 1 for x in data.values())
if max_len > 0 and self.is_scalar(data['datetime']):
    data['datetime'] = [data['datetime']] * max_len
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The `is_array()` and `is_scalar()` functions check whether `x` is an instance of any of `set, list, tuple, np.ndarray, pd.Series, pd.Index`.

It's not perfect, but hopefully the duct tape will hold until this can be fixed in Pandas.